# what's wrong with my shell script? when use loop in a function,always have some exception

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#adding values in an array
function addarray {
    local sum=0
    local newarray
    newarray=(`echo "$@"`)
    for value in $newarray
    do
        sum=$[ $sum+$value ]
    done
    echo $sum
}
myarray=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo "the origin array is : ${myarray[*]}"
arg1=`echo ${myarray[*]}`
echo $arg1
result=`addarray arg1`
echo "the result is $result
```

here is errormessage

```
the origin array is : 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
test11: line 9: 1 2 3 4 5: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 3 4 5")
the result is
```

---

My linux version is centos 7.0,and when i use loop only in script not in function,there will not be erros when process

Comment: `$[...]` is obsolete syntax, you should use `$(...)` for arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Why are you using `newarray`? Just do `for value in "$@"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `addarray $arg1`? You're missing the `$`. But I don't see how that would cause the error you got, so maybe it's a copying error.

Comment: The way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then it will show each line as it executes it, with variables expanded.

Comment: @Barmar You mean `$((...))` for arithmetic expressions, not `$(...)`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of sources of confusion here. First, whenever you use anything like `echo somethingorother` in backquotes, you're doing something weird and pointless; it takes the string (somethingorother in my example), converts it to output (of the `echo` command), then the backquotes capture the output and convert it back to a string. Net result: the `echo` and the backquotes effectively cancel each other, and you get the original string back. Well, mostly; there are several weird things that might happen to mess things up. Just skip both `echo` and backquotes, and use the string directly. So, for example, this line:

```
arg1=`echo ${myarray[*]}`
```

could be replaced by

```
arg1=${myarray[*]}
```

And BTW the name arg1 doesn't match what this variable contains or how it's used (well, sort of). It contains *all* the elements of `myarray`, not just the first. It also appears you meant its value to be passed as *all* of the arguments to `addarray` (although something different is happening, as I'll explain in a bit).

Second, you're handling arrays wrong. Take that command I just mentioned; it takes all the elements of the array, and sticks them together (with spaces between) into a single string, and stores that string in `arg1`. Thus, `myarray` was the array `("1" "2" "3" "4" "5")`, but `arg1` is just the single string "1 2 3 4 5".

There's some similar confusion inside the `addarray` function. You store the function's arguments as an array with this:

```
newarray=(`echo "$@"`)
```

(well, mostly -- this actually takes the arguments, carefully passes each on to `echo` as an argument, which sticks them together with spaces between, then that output is split into words based on spaces and each word is stored as an element of `newarray`. If there were any spaces within arguments, those will now be split into separate array elements, which is usually a mistake. Worse, if any of the arguments contain shell wildcards, they'll be replaced by a list of matching files. This isn't a problem here, but sometime you're going to try to pass "*" to a function to tell it to multiply, and it's going to wind up with a list of filenames and be very confused. The correct way to do this is `newarray=("$@")`.)

Then you refer to `newarray` as if it was just a plain string variable here:

```
for value in $newarray
```

This takes just the first element of `newarray` (you'd need `${newarray[@]}` or `${newarray[*]}` to get all the elements). Then since it's not double-quotes it splits that into words based on spaces, and then expands any wildcards into lists of matching filenames. When getting all elements of an array, you almost always want to use `"${newarray[@]}"` to get each element treated separately, but not word-split or wildcard-expanded.

Now the biggest problem. This line:

```
result=`addarray arg1`
```

runs the function `addarray`, and passes it the argument "arg1". Not the variable `arg1`, not its value ("1 2 3 4 5"), just the text string "arg1". Thus, inside the function, `newarray` gets just a single element, "arg1"; and the `for` loop runs once, with `value` set to "arg1". That means the line inside the loop:

```
sum=$[ $sum+$value ]
```

expands to:

```
sum=$[ 0+arg1 ]
```

but since the inside of `$[ ]` is an arithmetic context, the string "arg1" is implicitly treated as a variable name and expanded to its contents, giving:

```
sum=$[ 0+1 2 3 4 5 ]
```

in which the "2 3 4 5" part makes no sense, giving the error you see.

Now let me add several stylistic notes: when declaring a function, `funcname()` is more standard and portable than `function funcname`. Use `$(( ))` instead of its obsolete equivalent, `$[ ]`. Use `$( )` instead of backquotes to capture the output of a command -- it's easier to read, and backquotes have some weird syntactic consequences that can trip you up. Finally, it's best practice to put variable references in double-quotes (e.g. `echo "$sum"` instead of `echo $sum`), even when it's not strictly necessary.

Here's a corrected version:

```
#!/bin/bash
#adding values in an array
addarray() {
    local sum=0
    local newarray
    newarray=("$@")    # This keeps each argument a separate array element
    for value in "${newarray[@]}"    # This iterates over the elements cleanly
    do
        sum=$(( sum+value ))    # In arithmetic context, $ is not needed for variables
    done
    echo "$sum"
}
myarray=(1 2 3 4 5)
echo "the origin array is : ${myarray[*]}"    # [*] mashes the elements together with spaces between, but that's ok here
result=$(addarray "${myarray[@]}")    # Pass each array element as a separate argument
echo "the result is $result"
```

Oh, and one more recommendation: [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is great at pointing out common mistakes and bad practices in your scripts. While you're learning, run your scripts through it, and it'll save you from developing a variety of bad habits.